# When i use own sleep() function in javascript my recurency sorting function using quick sorting algorithm doesnt work

Tags: javascript, sorting, recursion

Hey I'm a beginner in js. I wanted to do quick sorting function. I have tables with values ​​and I would like to show how they change to show how the function works. Unfortunately the function is almost instantaneous so I did sleep function and added to the sorting function. After that the function didn't work in some cases (some values ​​were unsorted) I think it might have something to do with recursion. Please help how can i do it better? :)

(Other functions like selection sort or bubble sort works properly)

```js
var arr = new Array();
Array.prototype.swap = function (x,y) {
  var temp = this[x];
  this[x] = this[y];
  this[y] = temp;
  return this;
}
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}


function start_qs(){
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); // random integer from 0 - 100
        arr[i] =  value;
    }
    qs(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
}


function update(effect_id, array){
    document.getElementById(effect_id).innerHTML = "";
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        document.getElementById(effect_id).innerHTML += '<div class="label" style="height:'+array[i]+'px;">'+array[i]+'</div>';
    }
}
async function qs(array, left, right){
    let i = left;
    let j = right;
    x = array[Math.floor((left+right)/2)];
    while(i<=j){
        await sleep(50);
        while(array[i] < x && i < right){i++;}
        while(array[j] > x && j > left){j--;}
        if(i <= j){
            array.swap(i,j);
            i++;
            j--;
            update("quicksort", arr);
        }
    }
    if(left < j){qs(array, left, j);}
    if(i < right){qs(array, i, right);}
}

window.onload = function(){start_qs();}
```

```css
:root {
  --main: #202020;
  --sec: #D03737;
}

html{
    background: var(--main);
    color: var(--sec);
    font-size: 28px;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h3{text-align:center;}

.element{margin:auto;width:70%;}
.effect{width:60%;height:200px;margin:auto;}

.label{background: var(--sec); width:7%;margin:0 1.5%;color:black;text-align:center;font-size:0.75rem;}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/quickSort.js"/></script>
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">Javascript algorithms</h2>
        <div class="element" id="quicksorting" >
            <h3>Quick Sorting 
                <button style="border-radius:10px;padding:10px 30px;background:var(--main);border-color:var(--sec);color:var(--sec);" onclick="start_qs()">Restart</button></h3>
            <div class="content" style="display:flex;">
                <div class="effect" id="quicksort"  style="display:flex;align-items:flex-end;">
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The function parameter is `array`, but you're using `arr.swap()` and `arr.update()`.

Comment: @Barmar nah it's not about that passed function as array is same and interpreted as arr i think but i have tried your solution it's still the same

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Make sure you declare all your local variables. `x` in `qs()`, `i` in `update()`

Comment: That might not be the cause of your problem, but it's still important.

Comment: @Barmar sure i added code snippet i didn't know it's possible

Comment: I think it's because of sleep() function because code worked without it, mayby function swap doesnt run in order because of it and that this function is recursive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're calling the function recursively, you need to use `await` in the recursive calls. Otherwise the recursive calls will not execute until the current call finishes, and quicksort requires things all the recursive calls to execute in order.

Also declare `x` as a local variable, otherwise the recursive calls will overwrite its value.

```js
var arr = new Array();
Array.prototype.swap = function(x, y) {
  var temp = this[x];
  this[x] = this[y];
  this[y] = temp;
  return this;
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function start_qs() {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); // random integer from 0 - 100
    arr[i] = value;
  }
  qs(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
}

function update(effect_id, array) {
  document.getElementById(effect_id).innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    document.getElementById(effect_id).innerHTML += '<div class="label" style="height:' + array[i] + 'px;">' + array[i] + '</div>';
  }
}
async function qs(array, left, right) {
  let i = left;
  let j = right;
  let x = array[Math.floor((left + right) / 2)];
  while (i <= j) {
    await sleep(50);
    while (array[i] < x && i < right) {
      i++;
    }
    while (array[j] > x && j > left) {
      j--;
    }
    if (i <= j) {
      array.swap(i, j);
      i++;
      j--;
      update("quicksort", arr);
    }
  }
  if (left < j) {
    await qs(array, left, j);
  }
  if (i < right) {
    await qs(array, i, right);
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  start_qs();
}
```

```css
:root {
  --main: #202020;
  --sec: #D03737;
}

html {
  background: var(--main);
  color: var(--sec);
  font-size: 28px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.element {
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
}

.effect {
  width: 60%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.label {
  background: var(--sec);
  width: 7%;
  margin: 0 1.5%;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/quickSort.js" /></script>
<h2 style="text-align:center;">Javascript algorithms</h2>
<div class="element" id="quicksorting">
  <h3>Quick Sorting
    <button style="border-radius:10px;padding:10px 30px;background:var(--main);border-color:var(--sec);color:var(--sec);" onclick="start_qs()">Restart</button></h3>
  <div class="content" style="display:flex;">
    <div class="effect" id="quicksort" style="display:flex;align-items:flex-end;">

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```